# How do I remove the download button on the Vimeo Embedded Player?

Tags: wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-player

I am running an Online School Website using Wordpress and I want to embed Vimeo videos on my site. As my courses are paid, I don't want my students to be able to download the videos for offline viewing as this may lead to easy Piracy. So I want to remove the download icon shown in the image below:

[image: Image of Vimeo Player with Download button enabled]

So far I have tried the following:

1. Un-checking the box which says "What can people do with your videos? Download them" under the "Upload defaults" Settings.
2. Setting all my videos to "Hide on vimeo.com". I thought this would make anyone with the link unable to download them, but the icon is still showing.

Is there a way I can remove this icon or do I need to move my videos to another hosting platform which allows such basic privacy settings? I have the Vimeo Plus plan.

Comment: That download button isn't a standard part of the Vimeo player -- it might be WordPress itself or a browser extension that adds the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just culling an answer from the comments, as this question has invited non-answers. Quoting *@[Tommy Penner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704546/tommy-penner)*:

```
That download button isn't a standard part of the Vimeo player
-- it might be WordPress itself or a browser extension that adds the button.
```

So the first thing to do is check whether an extension is causing the button to appear. This obviously still leaves the scenario where your students might have some extension which causes the button to appear. The solution, as of the date of this post, appears to be to go into your privacy settings and uncheck the 'Allow Downloads' option. This should prevent even extensions from enabling that button.

```
You can disable downloads of your video by navigating to the video, selecting the Privacy option on the right side, and toggle off the Allow download switch at the top of the panel. The setting will automatically save.
```

Source: [Vimeo support site](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229678128-Downloading-videos).